# How to post a bug with Unicode text via Bugzilla REST API

Tags: web-services, unicode, bugzilla

I've got a problem when posting a bug with Unicode text.

My code in .NET looks like.

```
HttpWebRequest request = BugzillaService.MakeRequest(url, "POST");
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The code works well with ASCII text.

Unicode has been turn on with Bugzilla website, I could post a bug with Unicode text via website. But failed with Bugzilla REST service.

Do I miss something must be configured in Bugzilla website or REST service to support Unicode text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I miss something must be configured in Bugzilla website or REST service to support Unicode text?

Have you installed [this patch](http://hg.mozilla.org/webtools/bzapi/file/0d03fbe67e51/patches/xmlrpc-fix.diff)?

> Also, if you are using non-ASCII characters at all, you need to patch the BZ::Client module, which has an encoding bug. The patch for that is also in the patches directory.